# How do I install a Mac OS X theme for 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, themes

Additional details are:

- I've tried noobslab Mac OS X themes versions 1 and 2, they worked, 'Sort of.' They installed and are operating but they have some problems in as far as readability, which thing they didn't in 12.04.
- I've tried installing Macbuntu and it works but it has similar readability problems which weren't present in 12.04.

Comment: Wait for proper themes to appear, or learn how to edit them and fix what is not showing correctly.

Comment: I knew I could do that but I thought I might as well ask the question here in case someone has a more pleasant solution.

Comment: Tha main problem I see are contextual menus, or menus in general. The rest of the theme is working pretty much fine, you could edit that part only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Mac OS X theme, but if you are okay with Mac OS X-based theme then **Adwaita Cupertino** might work for you.

[image: Image from gnome-look.org]

Manual download and installation: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Adwaita+Cupertino?content=147061

PPA Installation: 
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/spice-up-your-desktop-with-these-5-cool.html

Comment: This is a good answer; only thing I have against it and the reason why I haven't accepted it is only somewhat similar to Mac OS X. But I realise it'd be quite the challenge to find a better answer.